# How to blanket change scaling of ui elements?

Tags: unity, kde, dpi, scaling

I have a large but not especially high resolution display. I don't want to change the font sizes, but rather I want to change how large everything appears other than text. I want to know how to do this on both unity and kde, as I use both very often. I know more or less how to do it for most things on kde, but I do not know how to change the size of buttons and menus. On unity I know how to change the size of the dockbar, but not the top bar or anything else pretty much, except for text which I do not want to change the size of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Unity Only**

I don't know how to do this in KDE but just happened to stumble upon this earlier today.

**STEP-ONE**

Go to system settings and adjust "scale for menu and title-bars". Initially, this will also affect your font size but we'll get to that in the next step.

[image]

**STEP-TWO**

Open unity-tweak-tool (if it's not installed it's available through apt-get). Choose "font" and adjust the "text scaling factor". As you can see in this example, the text gets smaller but the menusize, icons, panel, etc. stay the same. Actually, you are able to enlarge or reduce the size of the text without changing the size of the font. 
[image]